# Comparing “httpContext.User.Identity.Name” with active directory SamAccountName. Is this a correct approach?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ldap, httpcontext

I have the following:-

- I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web application.
- i am using Form authentication which authenticate users against the LDAP.

I have a table for storing SecurityGroup users. Where the table will have the SecurityGroupID + the users SamAccountName.

Then to check if the login user is within a given Security Group , I get the login username, as follow:-

```
string ADusername = httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Substring(httpContext.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
```

Then I check if the above Adusername string  is within any of the SamaccountName inside the SecurityGroup table. So in this case I am treating the SamAccountName as if it is the same as the `“httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Substring(httpContext.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);”`
I tested this approach and it worked well, but not sure if this approach might cause problems in the future. So I need help in these questions:-

1. The sameAccountName have the following format “FName.LastName” for example John.Smith. so let say in the future we had two users that have the same first name & last name. so in this will  the SamAccountName uniquly identify any user?
2. How do AD populate the SamAccountName? For example in the below picture , I think that SAMAccountName is the user login name (pre-windows 2000)? Is this correct. Where I can control its value, and does not have to be  Firstname.Lastname ?
   [image]
3. Currenly all our users inside the AD will have their `“httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Substring(httpContext.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1)”` equals to their SamAccountName. But will this rule always be true?
4. Does SamAccountName always uniquely identify users ? if yes will it also uniquely indent them cross-domains?
5. Is it better to use User Principal Name instead of samAccountname? and what does `string ADusername = httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Substring(httpContext.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);` exactly represents inside the AD?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to check if a user is a member of a group:

[GroupPrincipal.GetMembers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal.getmembers)

The sAMAccountName attribute is required to be unique in an Domain but not in a Forest. So `John.Smith` can exist multiple times in an AD Forest.

See here

[sAMAccountName](http://windowsitpro.com/active-directory/q-does-samaccountname-object-have-be-unique-active-directory-domain-or-entire-fores)

The sAMAccountName and UserPricncipalName does not have to be sn and givenName. You can use any value. You can control these values when you create an Account. Later you can also change them.

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes i am using active directory, but i am managing the security role inside my own database. for the AD i only use the users which exists there.. second question will "httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Substring(httpContext.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1) " retrive the SamAccountNamE?

Comment: If you use WindowsAuthentication in IIS it use the sAMAccountName. Maybe think about to use Windows Authentication with IIS. Then you don't need think about cookies and forms. Plus you can easily check membership of your user and you don't have to maintain another database. I use it for all my Intranet Applications.

Comment: Sorry, but the last comment is not correctly. What i mean is if you use Active Directory(not WindowsAuthentication) for your Authentication "and" your Security Management, then you can easily maintain your memberships. Because this is an feature of Active Directory. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739393%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: as i mentioned in my original question. i do not use windows authentication, i use form authentication , where a user enter his username and password, but i authenticate them using Ldap server